# Converting from screen space to world space, when using offsets (webgl)

Tags: glsl, webgl, antialiasing, coordinate-transformation

I have been transforming from screen space to world space like this:

```
//convert the window coordinates from gl_fragCoord to NDC coordinates: 
ndc.x = 2.0*((gl_FragCoord.x)/width-0.5); 
ndc.y = 2.0*((gl_FragCoord.y)/height-0.5);
ndc.z = (2.0*gl_FragCoord.z-far-near)/(far-near);

//convert the NDC coordinates to clip coordinates - gl_FragCoord.w = 1/w_clip: 
clip = vec4(ndc,1.0)/gl_FragCoord.w;   

//convert the clip coordinates to eye coordinates: 
eye = invproject*clip;

//convert eye coordinates to world space (with inverse view matrix)
objectpos = invmodel*eye;
```

And this works fine, but the problem is that I am trying to perform some antialiasing, where I offset the screen coordinate by som random value, so that the new coordinate is still within the screen pixel. I imagined that this could be done like this:

```
ndc.x = 2.0*((gl_FragCoord.x+half_pixelsize*random.x)/width-0.5);   
ndc.y = 2.0*((gl_FragCoord.y+half_pixelsize*random.y)/height-0.5);
ndc.z = (2.0*gl_FragCoord.z-far-near)/(far-near);
...
```

But then the problem is that I am still using the same z-coordinate, which should be different in eye space when changing the coordinates in screen space.

I've been told that this can be handled by reprojecting the z-coordinate: If one is given the original point, and the normal then one should reproject the distance from the original point to the new point, by using pythagoras. But I can't really understand what is meant by it, or if there maybe is another way to deal with this problem?